# encoding python

Tags: python, encode

i want to  concatenate some strings(Persian strings) in **python**:

```
            for t in lstres:
            with conn:
                c = conn.cursor()   
                q="SELECT fa FROM words WHERE en ='"+t+"'"
                c.execute(q)
                lst=c.fetchall()

                if lst:
                    W.append(lst)
                else:
                    W.append(t)

        cnum=1
        for can in W:
            cnum=cnum*len(W)

        candida=Set()

        for ii in range(1,min(20,cnum)):
            candid=""
            for w in W:
                candid+=str(" "+random.choice (w)[0]).encode('utf-8')
            candida.add(candid)
```

but it says :

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd8 in position 1: ordinal not in  range(128)
```

what is the problem ?

Comment: post the full traceback please...

Comment: I meant the error message, not the code ^^ also, the part where you fill `W` would be interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere along the line Python is trying to do an implicit type conversion from a unicode string to an ASCII encoded string.  Where this is happening is difficult to tell from what you've posted, but it's better to just make sure that you always use unicode anyway. To do this you need to add a `u` in front of all your strings like so: `u"A unicode string"` and always use `unicode()` instead of `str()`.

Unicode is often overlooked by English language programmers and tutorials because in English you can get away with just using ASCII encoded characters.  Unfortunately the rest of the world suffers for this because most languages use characters not supported by ASCII.  It might be useful to look over the Python [Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html) to get some guidance on good programming practice in Unicode.

I also found [this](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) article very useful.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
for ii in range(1,min(20,cnum)):
   candid=""
   for w in W:
       candid+=str(" "+random.choice (w)[0]).encode('utf-8')
    candida.add(candid)
```

It should be

```
for ii in range(1,min(20,cnum)):
    candid=u""
    for w in W:
        candid+=str(u" "+random.choice (w)[0]).encode('utf-8')
    candida.add(candid)
```

but it's not idiomatic python

you should do

```
for ii in range(1,min(20,cnum)):
     candida.add(u" ".join(random.choice (w)[0] for w in W))
```

moreover there is a potentiel sql injection in your script

```
q="SELECT fa FROM words WHERE en ='"+t+"'"
c.execute(q)
```

you should do

```
q="SELECT fa FROM words WHERE en =?"
c.execute(q, (t,))
```

`(t,)` is a tuple with only one element

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your strings as Unicode :

```
u'Your string here éàèç×...'
```